# Latex 12pt is different from actual font size 12 on Microsoft Word

Tags: fonts, fontsize, article, times

I have an assignment which I have written in Latex and I realized the prof has restrictions on Font Size and Font Name. The specification indicates that the document must be presented using "Times New Roman" font with size of 12.

using :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
```

outputs a result which is expected to be the same font size as 12 on Microsoft Word (presumably) - however, when compared to a printed document using Word, the font size of latex is smaller (around 11 on Word).

I read some where that Word uses `bp` so I changed it to `12bp` but it made it even smaller.

Comment: Do you use `\usepackage{times}`? LaTeX uses Computer Modern as default font.

Comment: @Ignasi The package [`times`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/times) is obsolete.

Comment: @Sverre Thanks, I didn't know it. In any case I was more interested into pointing that LaTeX uses computer modern which is not times.

Comment: @Ignasi I use `\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do *not* worry about these things. 99.9 % of people who ask for "Times New Roman 12pt" don't know what they mean by "Times New Roman", and they definitely don't know the first thing about point sizes. What they mean is that they want something that looks like what they get in their MS Word documents with Times New Roman 12pt.

Just use this and you're good to go:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tgtermes} % times font
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

You can't give `12bp` as an option to the `article` class, as it only knows `10pt`, `11pt`, and `12pt`. If you try to specify `12bp` it'll just give you the warning `Unused global option(s): [12bp]` and fall back on the default setting `10pt`.

Comment: does this make any changes at all? because it looks exactly like the latex default font

Comment: @Kyle No. Remove `\usepackage{tgtermes}` and you'll see the latex default font.